How do I read SMS messages in Android (13 and above) using an Android app?
I am an Android developer working on a startup project that involves reading SMS messages from a specific number. However, due to restrictions in Android 12 and above, the app no longer has permission to read SMS messages directly. Is there an alternative method or workaround to access SMS messages under these new restrictions?
    private void checkSmsPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION);
        } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_SEND_SMS_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_READ_SMS_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted for reading SMS
                    queryLatestSmsMessages();
                } else {
                    // Permission denied for reading SMS
                    showToast("Permission to read SMS denied.");
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_SEND_SMS_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted for sending SMS
                } else {
                    // Permission denied for sending SMS
                    showToast("Permission to send SMS denied.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerSmsReceiver() {
        smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        if (pdus != null) {
                            for (Object pdu : pdus) {
                                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                                String sender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                                String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                                handleSmsMessage(sender, messageBody);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(smsReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void handleSmsMessage(String sender, String messageBody) {
        String messageHash = sender + "|" + messageBody;
        if (receivedMessageHashes.contains(messageHash)) {
            Log.d("SmsReceiver", "Duplicate message detected. Ignoring.");
            return;
        }
        receivedMessageHashes.add(messageHash);

        Log.d("SmsReceiver", "Sender: " + sender);
        Log.d("SmsReceiver", "Message Body: " + messageBody);

        if (!currentStater.getStarter_phone_number().isEmpty() && sender.contains(currentStater.getStarter_phone_number())) {
            Log.d("SmsReceiver", "Received SMS from starter: " + currentStater.getStarter_phone_number());

            if (messageBody.contains("3-PHASE OK")) {
                status.setText("3-PHASE OK");
                phase1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
                phase2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
                phase3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
                isActivated = false;
                isActivated1 = false;
                isActivated2 = false;
            } else if (messageBody.contains("Line Fault")) {
                status.setText("Line Fault");
                phase1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
                phase2.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
                phase3.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_btn_background);
            }
        }
    }


Why use SMS?  Particularly from a specific number.  If this is a server, using a web service and/or push messaging is a far better solution.  If this is a personal phone sending smses, you probably still should build a network layer solution in there.  SMS is not a particularly great way of sending information, and the security/privacy concerns of using it means any app looking to read it is more likely to be malware than legit.

Listen to Gabe, but to answer the specific issue here: the READ_SMS permission is for querying the SMS Provider. To catch incoming SMS in a Receiver like that, you need the RECEIVE_SMS permission instead. It's unclear why this wasn't an issue for you until 12 or 13, but prior to 8, granting one permission in a group actually granted all of them in the group, so maybe you were getting RECEIVE_SMS by accident 'cause it was previously granted on upgraded devices? Beyond that, I'm not aware of any changes in 12 or 13 that would have caused that particular setup to fail otherwise.

I just remembered, there is something in 14 that would cause a problem there: Runtime-registered broadcasts receivers must specify export behavior. Basically, you'd need to add Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED as a third argument to your registerReceiver() call. Just FYI.
